# Linear Mixed Modelling: Vastly different parameter estimates when adding fixed effect that is already present as random effect

Tags: mixed-model

For context: For one of my student's projects, we are looking at how simulated eye-height in VR and real-world posture (Sitting, Lying, Standing) interact in the perception of size. Our participants judge the size of a virtual object at different simulated distances in front of them while they are sitting, lying, or standing in the real world, and while we simulate different eye-heights in the VR environment.

Now as for my stats question – for the analysis I have two LMMs:

```r
M1: Perceived Size ~ Posture*EyeHeight + 
                     (Distance + Posture + EyeHeight| Participant)

M2: Perceived Size ~ Posture*EyeHeight + Distance + 
                     (Distance + Posture + EyeHeight| Participant)
```

Posture is a categorical variable with four levels, and EyeHeight and Distance are continuous.

My problem: M1 and M2 yield vastly different regression coefficients for the main effect of Posture. Anyone got any ideas why? The estimate for EyeHeight and the interaction terms between EyeHeight and Posture are nearly identical between M1 and M2. Judging from the plots and from the previous research, the result from M2 is more likely to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Both these models estimate a separate `Size~Distance` slope for each participant, but M1 forces the mean of these slopes to be zero.  That's typically not a sensible assumption; if you think perceived size varies with distance for each participant, it usually makes sense to allow for the slope to be non-zero on average as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I use the lme4 package for R, and when I extract the per-paricipant slopes for Distance with ranef(M1)$Participant$Distance, the mean of these slopes is different from zero, and pretty much the same value as the regression coefficient for the fixed effect for Distance in M2. The mean of the per-participant slopes for Distance for M2 is 0 as expected. So it doesn't seem to be the case that M1 forces the mean of the per-participant slopes for Distance to be zero.